# Select all table rows between headers using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom

Having the following automatically generated table layout (I have nearly no influence over it)

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>First Header</th>
      <th>
         <a href="#" class="used-for-some-action">show/hide</a>
      </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>A question?</td>
      <td><input value="User's answer" /></td>
   </tr>
   <!-- Some more rows -->

   <tr>
      <th>Second Header</th>
   </tr>

   <!-- Some more question blocks -->
</table>
```

... I'd like to select all the `<tr>`-elements between two headers using Javascript/jQuery
in order to provide such features like:

- Hiding all the questions belonging to a certain header.
- Automatically edit the `<input>`s (*eg.* check/uncheck all *or* restore default)

The links causing the desired actions are already in the correct headers.

What would be the best way to approach this issue?

Comment: A good place to start would be to add a class to each`<tr>` that contains headers - so that when you are traversing the DOM you don't have to go up and down through parents / children unnecessarily.

Comment: But he doesn't have control over HTML.

Comment: do u want to select `<th>`s or `<tr>`s

Comment: @Mahmoud Farahat I actually want to select only the `<tr>`s which contain `<td>`s. The question blocks, as I called them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to solve this problem.

```
function getRows(start){
    return start.nextUntil(function(i, v){
        return $('th', v).length > 0;
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KNvev/5/)

Implementation of Show/Hide

```
$('table').on('click', '.used-for-some-action', function(){
    getRows($(this).closest('tr')).toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KNvev/6/)

**Update:**
Based on comments by @BLSully

```
$('table').on('click', '.used-for-some-action', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').nextUntil('tr:has(th)').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KNvev/8/)

Comment: `nextUntil`...where the heck did that method come from?! Haha never heard of it, good thinking :)

Comment: @Arun P Johny How should I perform an action on each of the elements? In his answer Mohamed Ali says I should use `this`.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. An alternative, just for argument's sake might be: `start.nextUntil('tr:has(th)')`

Comment: @BLSully yes, That is the best one

Comment: @BLSully probably you should post it as an answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Eh, It's not materially much different than your answer... just wanted to give an alternate to future readers

Answer (score 1):

I like Arun P Johny's answer. Here's what I originally thought (this code implements the hide/show functionality)

```
$(".used-for-some-action").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    $(this).parents("tr").next().is(":visible") ? $(this).parents("tr").next().hide() : $(this).parents("tr").next().show();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DQMht/1/

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it real simple. You're using JavaScript, so when the page loads, just add a class to rows with a `<th>`, then use the class.

```
$(function() {
    $("th").parent().addClass("hasTH");
});
```

Then you can simply target rows that have the `hasTH` class.

---

Another option would be to still do it when the page loads, but instead of adding a class, group the rows into new `<tbody>` elements.  This would give you the most pure DOM representation.

Comment: Is this really possible? I always thought there could be only one `<tbody>` in the table.

Comment: @Jakub: There can be as many `<tbody>` as you like. That's part of the point of them. It gives you a valid way to logically group rows. If you're needing to fix the DOM because you don't control the source, that's the approach I'd take because that's what I would have done on the server.

Comment: ...either way, I'd avoid repeated complex DOM selection in favor of fixing the DOM to provide the clean selection process you would have created if you controlled the source.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("tr:has(th)").each(function(){
    if ($(this).find('th').length==2) {
        // here you have this: that represent the row which have two td
    }
})
```